# I'm using mysql-connector-c++ 1.1.9 but I'd like to connect to the mysql db via socket not tcp

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

Does the library allow for connecting to the db via socket or do you have to use tcp and if so does anybody know the correct format?

```
/* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock", "user1", "passphrase");
```

I just get a connection refused from the db

```
# ERR: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111 "Connection refused") (MySQL error code: 2003, SQLState: HY000 )
```

Comment: I don't see how you can be getting that error from your code. You didn't give an IP address.

Comment: Looks like this works!

con = driver->connect("unix:///var/run/mysql/mysql.sock", "user1", "passphrase");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-connect-options.html) the first argument to `connect()` should be in the form of a URL, and the `unix:` protocol is used to refer to a Unix-domain socket. So it should be:

```
con = driver->connect("unix:///var/run/mysql/mysql.sock", "user1", "passphrase");
```

I guess it defaults to `tcp://127.0.0.1` when it can't parse the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
/* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("unix:///var/run/mysql/mysql.sock", "user1", "passphrase");
```

Check if the unix socket file is working.